# XYZ layer not requesting tiles until map is moved

Tags: openlayers-3

I load an XYZ layer as

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: advanced.name ? advanced.name : "XYZ Layer " + new Date().getTime,
                source: source ? source :new ol.source.XYZ({
                    url: url
                })
            })
map.addLayer(layer);
```

It successfully will add the layer, but it doesn't request the tiles until the map is moved, so to the user nothing has changed. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you try to add this `layer` together with the map constructor?